# Find P(Y < 3X) with X and Y uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

X and Y are independent continuous random variables, with X uniformly distributed on the interval [0, θ] and Y uniformly distributed on the interval [0, 2θ].

Find P(Y < 3X).

Options -

1. 1/6
2. 1/3
3. 1/2
4. 2/3